# How to set ylim and other graph parameters on MPLFinance plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, candlestick-chart

I am using **mplfinance** (https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) to plot OHLC candlestick charts.
The code is simple:
`mpf.plot(Data, type='candle', figscale = 2)`
How can I control the display (range, scaling) of the y-axis?
For example, I want to set the range to exactly from 1.1 to 1.2, with ticks every 0.02
Thank you for any help you can provide !

Comment: Not an answer but I'd suggest making a comment or raising an issue on the repo since it is fairly active - you may have a better chance of getting a response there instead of SO. 

Also, on SO, it is always a good practice to lay out what you have tried already along with the question. That helps people to help you. 

Cheers!